# Who sees my comments on my friend's posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

A friend of mine posts updates on his timeline and sets their privacy to be only shared with his friends. I am on his friends list, so I can see his posts. But, if I were to comment on his posts, who else would be able to see my comment?

Will my friends see my comment? Assume my other friends are not on his friends list.

Can my comment show up in Google Search?

Answer (score 1):

His posts would be able to be seen by friends only, so your comments would be able to be seen by his friends unless he changes the privacy scope on you later on. Google would not be able to index your comment; if you log off of Facebook entirely and go to his page you'll be able to see what Google sees. Your friends would not be able to see his post at all if they're not his friends as well.

Comment: Last line of your answer is not true, his post is not visible to OP's friends till the time OP has not commented or liked that post. Once OP did, it will be visible to OP's friend, but due to post privacy setting OP's friend would not be able to like or comment on that post.

Answer (score 1):

As your friend has set privacy as "Friends", so all his friends would be able to see all the activity on that post. So your comment would be visible for his friends. And your comment would be visible for your friends as well. Your friends will not be able to comment or like his post, but your comment will be visible for them as it shows on your friend's feed something like *'you have commented on that post'*.

And no it would not be show up on Google search.

Comment: Someone downvoted this answer, may I know why? What did you find wrong here?